# In Romans 2:12-14 is Paul saying there are two judgments?

Tags: textual-criticism, romans

Romans 2:12-14 (NKJV)

> 12 For as many as have sinned without law will also perish without law,  and as many as have sinned in the law will be judged by the law 13 (for  not the hearers of the law are just in the sight of God, but the doers of  the law will be justified; 14 for when Gentiles, who do not have the law,  by nature do the things in the law, these, although not having the law, are  a law to themselves,

Is Paul saying that God will judge the gentiles with one measure of judgment & the Jews with another measure of judgement

Comment: What do you mean by measure? That God is lighter on one than the other?

Answer (score 1):

Shalom Collen.

If you look at the words themselves, they say that those who have sinned without law will also PERISH without law. The words do not say that this group of people will not be JUDGED by the law.

This just serves to highlight that the law is good in that it aims to prevent people from going down the path of death, or dying before their time.

The subsequent words point to both Jews and Gentiles being judged by what they do instead of what they hear (the Gentiles did and do not have the privilege of hearing the laws of Judaism).

The Gentiles, also, by nature do the things in the law, meaning, their own conscience tells them what is right and wrong (this conscience of right and wrong came from eating from the Tree of KNOWLEDGE of GOOD and EVIL).

The Church, on the other hand, lives by another law, called THE LAW OF THE SPIRIT OF LIFE, which is life through FAITH, not effort - THE RIGHTEOUS SHALL LIVE BY FAITH.

Be blessed.

Hannah David
Singapore

Comment: @ Hannah David thanks, All have sinned & come short of the glory of God,we shall all stand before the judgement seat of Christ,but Davi what i was alluding to in the above text is  that it seemed as if there was one kind of judgment for those who have sinned without the law & another kind of judgment for those who have sinned  under the law,Davi you should back your answers with some citations either from the Bible or other renowned bible commenters

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange Hannah, thanks for contributing! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us. [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423)

Comment: Please keep in mind that whilst many of us are Christians [this is not a Christian site](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/441/423). Be sure to [check out what makes us different from other sites that study the Bible](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423).